# References for numerical stochastic differential equations

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, stochastic-processes

I am currently working on a topic in physics which requires me to solve stochastic differential equations (specifically stoch. Schrödinger equation).

I am a physicist and have not had any mathematical course on stochastics (just some statistical physics).

I am looking for a book/reference to use as an introduction to numerical solution of SDE, possibly with theoretical background but mostly  application/implementation-oriented.

So far I have unearthed the book by Kloeden & Platen from the library of my university but am still looking for something other, hopefully easier to understand.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kloeden/Platen is the standard reference.

For a straightforward, useful (as in coded!) introduction see Higham's paper [An Algorithmic Introduction to Numerical Simulation of Stochastic Differential Equations](http://www.caam.rice.edu/%7Ecox/stoch/dhigham.pdf) and references therein. The link to the code in the original paper has been deprecated, but is now available [on GitHub](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/117855-algorithmic-introduction-to-numerical-stochastic-diffeqs).